# Hide part of rounded border with css

Tags: html, css

I have rounded border around div with a hidden part like in image below. It has to be `display: flex` and should not move around.

I tried adding only bot and left border, and creating top border with div, but the rounding is a bit off. Any suggestions would be welcomed here, thanks.

EDIT: i only need to hide border, inside of the div should be visible

[image: border]

Comment: Can you provide a code you've got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pseudo elements to achieve this. You may need to position them according to your layout and content

```css
#border {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: solid 2px black;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;  
}
#border::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  border-top: solid 2px black;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

#border::after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 244px;
  left: -2px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 5px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="border"> 
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```